# Expected 4 positional argument but got 5

Tags: python

I came across a python problem where it gives the error "Expected 4 positional argument but got 5"

I want to create an object with every line in the file. The class takes four arguments. 
This is the file:

```
 B.Borg 10 15 0.67
 B.Becker 2 15 0.13
 B.Bingley 3 15 0.20
```

and my class:

```
    class Spelareinfo:
        def __init__(self, namn, vunna_match, antal_match, andel_vunna):
            self.__namn = namn
            self.__vunna_match = vunna_match
            self.__antal_match = antal_match
            self.__andel_vunna = andel_vunna

        def __str__(self):
            spelare = str(self.__namn)+"\t  "+ str(self.__vunna_match)+ "\t  "+str(self.__antal_match)+"\t  "+str(self.__andel_vunna)
            return spelare

        def get_namn(self):
            return self.__namn

        def get_vunna_match(self):
            return self.__vunna_match

        def get_andel_vunna(self):
            return self.__andel_vunna
```

and this is how i divided every line in the file:

```
    def skapa_spelare(spelare):
        spelarelistan = []
        for x in spelare:
            y = x.split()
            p = Spelareinfo(y[0],y[1],y[2],y[3])
            print (p)
```

and the error is:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

I tried to figure out where is the error, so i tried the following code:

```
list1 = ['B.Borg', '10', '15', '0.67']
list2 = ['B.Bingley', '3', '15', '0.20']
list3= ['B.Becker', '2', '15', '0.13']

print(Spelareinfo(list1[0],list1[1],list1[2],list1[3]))
```

It gives the same error.

Comment: Are you sure you are giving you're code as you have it? I ran it and it did not return any error

Comment: @cmxu there's a lot of other things, so I picked the part shows error.

Comment: I created the class with your code exactly and then ran the `p=...` line and it created the object. I see no problem with your init code. There must be something else.

Comment: @cmxu
yes, I noticed that before I asked the question, it should be ``` for x in spelare: y = x.split() p = Spelareinfo(y[0],y[1],y[2],y[3])``` but I tried every single index, they are all for on argument

Comment: I'm saying the error doesn't make sense from the code you posted. I'm just asking you post more, or indicate where this occurs or provide data or something.

Comment: @cmxu I dont know, I tried to edit the question and add me entire code, but it wont let me go through and keep ask me for more details.

Comment: I think it just wants to know why you are editing and what you changed, just say something like 'added more code'

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: Note that you can change `Spelareinfo(list1[0],list1[1],list1[2],list1[3])` to `Spelareinfo(*list1)` if `list1` has exactly the same number of items as there are arguments to `Spelareinfo.__init__()`.